# Check .length before applying substr()?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, is it better to do this:

```
var string = 'hello';
if(string.length > 10) {
    string = string.substr(0,10);
}
```

or simply:

```
var string = 'hello';
string = string.substr(0,10);
```

I know the performance difference between the two won't be anything huge but I like my JS to run as lightly as possible!

Which is the best to use?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you are going to do this a couple hundred thousand times inside a loop, the question is moot. I 'd go with the second because it does the exact same thing and it's shorter.

Comment: If the `IF` statement has no impact on the outcome, why would you keep it?

Comment: @MikeHayes: Thinking about performance is a desirable step in the evolution of a developer. Knowing when not to do that is much harder, so don't worry.

Comment: Substr - Returns the characters in a string beginning at the specified location through the specified number of characters. Made jsfiddle for you: alerts hello: http://jsfiddle.net/8dXMR/2/ If condition will have no advantage over substr call nor any big performance upgrades, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only use the `if` if it were to express some business logic. (e.g.

```
if (string.length > someConfiguredMaxLength) {
}
```

this way you'll automatically add a readable comment to your code which makes it better to understand.

Regarding the peformance, i'd say:

*Premature optimization is the root of all evil* -- DonaldKnuth

Answer (score 1):

Or, may be you can combine both

```
var str = 'hello'; 
str = str.length > 10 ? str.substr(0,10) : str;
```